# iOS - Expand UICollectionView height using Auto Layout as new cells are added

Tags: ios, dynamic, height, autolayout, uicollectionview

I am building a collection view that will allow a user to add data as they want.
The collection view will start out small (screen width, 30px height), and I want it to grow in height as new cells/rows are added. It should stop growing when it hits the bottom of the view controller's view.

The collection view is the ONLY view in the view controller (just for testing purposes and starts out just below the top layout guide (below status bar).

I tried adding the following constraints to the collection view, but it doesn't grow (and I have constraint warnings in storyboard of "Inequality Constraint Ambiguity"):

```
Leading Space
Trailing Space
Top Space to Superview
Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide >= 0
Height >= 30
```

What am I doing wrong? What constraints (in storyboard) do I need to add/fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should tweak it in your code. You need to calculate each row height in your collection view plus the internal spacing between each row, and after a cell was added you call these methods

```
collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(a,b,c,d) // Adapt new frame to expand height 
collectionView
```